# Корректность программы без инстанциации шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
void foo() {

}

template<int arg>
void bar() {
    foo(arg);
}


int main() {

}
```

Почему эта программа компилируется msvc ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/niM0QY)), но не компилируется gcc и clang ([2](https://godbolt.org/z/B0EH04) и [3](https://godbolt.org/z/41UKCg))? Должна ли она компилироваться в соответствии со стандартом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандарт позволяет (но не обязывает) компиляторам проверять, что шаблон является корректным до инстанцирования. т.е. данная программа является *плохо сформированной* (*ill-formed*), а поведение вышеперечисленных компиляторов является допустимым.

**[12.7.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8)**

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
> - ...

**Вольный перевод**

> Корректность шаблона может быть проверена до какого-либо инстанцирования. Программа является плохо сформированной (но не выдача сообщения об ошибке не обязательня) если:
>
> - Ни какая корретная специализация шаблона или подвыражение `constexpr` не могут быть сгенирированы, если выражение в шаблоне и сам шаблон не будут [явно] инстанцированы; или
> - ...

Answer (score 5):

Программа компилируется в MSVС++ потому, что в режиме по умолчанию (см. "P.S." ниже) компилятор MSVC++ неправильно реализует так называемый *двухфазное разрешение имен* для шаблонов (two-phase lookup).

В C++ контекст, в котором выполняется разрешение имен, использованных в определении шаблона, зависит от того, является ли данное имя *зависимым* от шаблонных параметров. Для имен, которые НЕ являются зависимыми, разрешение имен выполняется сразу, в контексте определения шаблона. Для зависимых имен разрешение имен откладывается: оно выполняется из точки инстанциирования шаблона (с некоторым нюансами).

В данном случае имя `foo` в  `foo(arg)` НЕ является зависимым именем. Это означает, что name lookup для этого выражения должен выполняться сразу, непосредственно при компиляции определения шаблона. Так как подходящией версии функции `foo` оттуда не видно, код является ошибочным.

MSVC++ не делит имена на зависимые и независимые, а просто откладывает разрешение *всех* имен, использованных в определении шаблона, до момента инстанциирования шаблона. Так как в данном случае инстанциирования не происходит вообще, name lookup в MSVC++ не производится вообще и ошибка не обнаруживается.

Можно упростить код, полностью избавив внутренний вызов от какой-то зависимости от параметров шаблона

```
template <typename T> void foo()
{
  bar(5);
}

void bar(int) {}

int main()
{
  foo<double>();
}
```

Такой код успешно скомпилируется MSVC++, причем вызов `bar(5)` из определения шаблона будет направлен в функцию `bar(int)` объявленную позже. На самом деле такой код совершенно некорректен. Компилятор был обязан выполнить name lookup для `bar` сразу при трансляции определения шаблона и, не найдя ничего, сообщить об ошибке.

А вот в таком примере компилятор обязан вызвать именно `void bar(char)` версию функции, в то время как компилятор MSVC++ вызовет `void bar(int)`

```
void bar(char) {}

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
  bar(5);
}

void bar(int) {}

int main()
{
  foo<double>();
}
```

P.S. Как заметил @ixSci в комментариях, включив "Conformance Mode" в установках проекта (флаг `/permissive-`) вы можете заставить компилятор MSVC++ вести себя корректно в таких ситуациях.

Comment: Справедливости ради, в MS этим вопросом активно занимаются, и оба примера из Вашего ответа корректно отработают на последней версии компилятора msvc.

Comment: @ixSci: У меня полностью заапдейченный VS2017, но там - неправильно.

Comment: А флаг `permissive-` выставлен?

Comment: @ixSci: Хм... Да, `permissive-` помогает.

Comment: Без `permissive-` используется старый компилятор; в студии стоит всегда собирать с этим флагом, если нет потребности в обратном. С этим флагом используется другой компилятор, тот, что они сейчас активно разрабатывают.